# Get Attribute object from INamedTypeSymbol.GetAttributes() i.e. AttributeData object?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have defined the following attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
class DemoAttribute : Attribute
{
  public string SomeInfo { get; }

  public DemoAttribute(string someInfo)
  {
    this.SomeInfo = someInfo;
  }
}
```

which can be applied to some class as follows:

```
[Demo("hello world")]
class Program { }
```

An `INamedTypeSymbol` variable `namedTypeSymbol` pointing to the `Program` class is provided to me with which I managed to get the name of the attribute.

```
foreach(var attr in namedTypeSymbol.GetAttributes())
{
  if(attr.AttributeClass.Name == "DemoAttribute") { ... }
}
```

But how do I access what was set as `SomeInfo`?

Comment: Don't really know if this will help (did not have time to check), but try looking at attr.NamedArguments property.

Comment: @PonasJustas Is it correct that there is no way to "translate" from Roslyn types like `AttributeData` to reflection types like `Attribute`?

Comment: @David correct. Roslyn and Reflection should be regarded as two different worlds. Sometimes they have a similar representation (like `MetadataName`) but actual objects don't translate anywhere as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways you can pass arguments to attributes.  Either by setting the property (`[Demo(SomeInfo="hello world")]`) or via the constructor, as you are doing.  If you used the named approach, Ponas would be correct that the solution lies in `NamedArguments`.

However, as you are using the constructor, the data is located in `ConstructorArguments`.  This is an array of `TypedConstant`, from which you can get the value `"hello world"`:

```
string attributeData = (string)attr.ConstructorArguments[0].Value;
```