# Get enclosing type from SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext in HandleTypeDeclaration(...)

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I my analyzer I have the following registration:

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
  context.RegisterCompilationStartAction(HandleCompilationStart);
}

private static void HandleCompilationStart(CompilationStartAnalysisContext context)
{
  context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(
    HandleTypeDeclaration,
    ImmutableArray.Create(SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration, SyntaxKind.StructDeclaration, SyntaxKind.InterfaceDeclaration));
}

private static void HandleTypeDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
  var x = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(context.Node);
  ...
}
```

In `HandleTypeDeclaration` I want to access the type the analyzer is currently processing in order to check if the type was attributed by some attribute I want to use to mark types which should not be analyzed (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919957/get-attribute-object-from-inamedtypesymbol-getattributes-i-e-attributedata-ob)).

In my locals window I saw that `SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context` has a property named `ContainingSymbol` which has the  however this member does not show up in Intellisense. I have come up with the guess `var x = ...` but is it always equivalent? How can I access `ContainingSymbol` on `context`? Is it the correct way at all to get the enclosing type?

[image: locals window]

Comment: What's the version of your referenced CodeAnalysis nuget package? It's probably not the latest 1.2 version, while your VS has update 2.

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common and .CSharp is 1.0.0 (latest is 1.2.1) and microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers os 1.0.0 (latest is 1.1.0)

Comment: I see. In version 1.0.0 the `SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext` didn't contain the property `ContainingSymbol`. VS sees it because you have an update which already contains it. If you have no requirement of being backward compatible, then you could upgrade to 1.2.1, and use the property.

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam: Me having the requirement of being backward compatible, can I use `context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(context.Node)` instead safely?

Comment: Yes, you can/should use that. I'm not sure what you mean by safely. I tend to check if the returned symbol is null or not.

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam: Safely meaning always returning the same result like `ContainingSymbol`.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. The purpose seems to be the same, but I don't know if the behavior matches 100%. (It should) I'm adding the above comment as an answer, so that the question can be marked answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 1.0.0 the `SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext` didn't contain the property `ContainingSymbol`. VS sees it because you have an update which already contains it.

If you have backward compatibility requirements till VS 2015 RTM, then you have no other choice than to use `context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(context.Node)`, which works in Roslyn 1.0. This should be equivalent to `context.ContainingSymbol` in newer Roslyn versions.